# sql server query equivalent to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Whats the equivalent of this query to mysql?

```
SELECT [training_id], Convert(varchar, [trainingDate], 101) +  '-'  +  [trainingHour] as trainingDate FROM [tbl_training] WHERE openSeats > 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT training_id, 
    CONCAT(trainingDate,"-",trainingHour) AS trainingDate 
FROM tbl_training
WHERE openSeats > 0
```

Comment: i tried this but no output, how can I test the query?  $database->setQuery('SELECT training_id,CONCAT(trainingDate,"-",trainingHour AS trainingDate FROM training WHERE openSeats > 0');

Comment: CONCAT(trainingDate,"-",trainingHour) instead of CONCAT(trainingDate,"-",trainingHour

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
        DATE_FORMAT(trainingDate, '%c/%d/%Y'), '-', trainingHour
    ) AS trainingDate 
FROM tbl_training WHERE openSeats > 0;
```

`DATE_FORMAT` should allow you to get your `CONVERT` effect from MSSQL..

Comment: this one doesnt work meabe the parenthesis or something:            $database->setQuery('SELECT training_id,CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(trainingDate, '%c/%d/%Y'), '-', trainingHour) AS trainingDate FROM training ');

Comment: it will help if you give sample data and output.. and oh, don't forget the `;` --i updated my post